# SQL Server: the identity column must be of data type int, bigint, smallint, tinyint, decimal, or numeric

Tags: sql-server

I use SQL Server 2017 Management Studio, and I try to create encrypted columns (with always encrypted task) and I get an error

> The identity column must be of data type int, bigint, smallint, tinyint, decimal, or numeric with a scale of 0, unencrypted, and constrained to be nonnullable.

My tables are:

```
create table testDB.dbo.Login
(
    ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Username varchar(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    Password varchar(128) NOT NULL,
    Email varchar(100) Not Null UNIQUE
);

create table testDB.dbo.Admin
(
    ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Admin INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES testDB.dbo.Login(ID)
);
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: error raised by sql server or another platform?

Comment: Which datatype have you set for the IDENTITY field? In above example, it is "int" only, so it should not raise any error.

Comment: @HasanFathi error raised by sql server

Comment: @Mittal I used with SQL-Server 2017

Comment: So, you tried to encrypt the identity column

Comment: @Mittal You right. I can't encrypt the identity column?

Answer (score 0):

For format identity key Try this:

"padded_id" was the name I used in the computed column example.

```
create table table
(
   id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
   padded_id AS (right('0000000000' + CONVERT(varchar(10),id),10)) PERSISTED 
    NOT NULL,
   other columns....
)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try Encrypting Other columns Leaving the Identity Column and Foreign Key Reference Columns.**